# Custom attribute use base class value as parameter

Tags: c#, .net

I have this attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class PersonAttribut : Attribute
{
    Person person;

    public PersonAttribut(Person perosn)
    {
        this.person = person;

        if (.............)
        {
            throw new Exception("My comment");
        }
    }
}
```

In a class:

```
public abstract class MyPersonBase
{
    protected readonly Person person;

    public MyPersonBase(Person person)
        => this.person = person;
}

public class MyPerson : MyPersonBase
{
    public MyPerson(Person person) : base(person)
    {
    }

    [Person(person)]
    public void MyMethod(Person person)
    {
    }
}
```

I'd like send as parameter (see method : `MyMethod`) to the attribute the value `person` of the base class `MyPersonBase` but I get this error :
*An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property*

How can I do?

Comment: Instead of passing the Person in, Use reflection to find the instance of the class in which the attribute is placed on

Comment: @johnny5 Possible to access the value of the property of the current instance using reflection ? From the attribute ?

Comment: After I left the comment I did a bit of research but I didn't find much. Maybe a way to grab it using the stack frame but if there was it wouldn't be pretty or quick.  It looks like your trying to implement guards.  It might be easier to just create a validate method instead which only kicks in when the attribute is present

Comment: Whatever you're trying to accomplish can't be done via attribute because per the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/attributes, values passed into attribute declarations must be constants, types, or 1-dimensional arrays of either of those two. You may want to look at aspect-oriented programming, which syntactically can be done like an attribute, but you'll be able to have access to the argument values of the method.